# Trying to make a embed slash command but ran into a problem

Tags: javascript, discord.js

```
The error:
CombinedError (2)
  Received one or more errors

  1 ValidationError > s.nullish
  |   Expected undefined or null
  |
  |   Received:
  |   | [Function: displayAvatarURL]

  2 ValidationError > s.string
  |   Expected a string primitive
  |
  |   Received:
  |   | [Function: displayAvatarURL]
```

I've looked back on my code but everything looks good so far. This is only in my embed.js file and no where else.
The code:

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder, EmbedBuilder } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName("embed")
        .setDescription('Return an embed.'),
    async execute(interaction, client) {
        const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
            .setTitle(`This is an EMBED`)
            .setDescription('This is a EMBED description')
            .setColor(0xFA03CA)
            .setImage(client.user.displayAvatarURL())
            .setThumbnail(client.user.displayAvatarURL())
            .setTimestamp(Date.now())
            .setAuthor({
                url: `https://www.twitch.tv/x333en`,
                iconURL: interaction.user.displayAvatarURL(),
                name: interaction.user.tag
            })
            .setFooter({
                iconURL: client.user.displayAvatarURL(),
                text: client.user.tag
            })
            .setURL(`https://discord.gg/8YtDhpbCJf`)
            .addFields([
                {
                    name: `Field 1`,
                    value: `Field Value 1`,
                    inline: true
                },
                {
                    name: `Field 2`,
                    value: `Field value 2`,
                    inline: true
                }
            ]);

        await interaction.reply({
            embeds: [embed]
        })
    }
```

This is my code as of right now.

I've tried to move stuff around but it seem to cause more issues so i just left it be.

Comment: The code you posted for your "embed.js" works for me, so it seems like the error is elsewhere

Comment: It seems like you forgot parentheses somewhere in your code - not in `embed.js`.
Try looking for `displayAvatarURL` and change it to `displayAvatarURL()`

Comment: Ah thanks for letting me know that it works. I retyped displayAvatarURL and ran npm run test and it seem to do the trick. Should've done that in the first place but i didn't know if that was going to work or not lol. Thanks again!